# Extract Date from string using regex in Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, datetime

I have this data extracted from Email body

```
Data=("""-------- Forwarded Message --------          

Subject:    Sample Report

Date:   Thu, 6 Apr 2017 16:39:19 +0000

From:   test1@abc.com

To:     test2@xyz.com""")
```

I want to extract this particular date and month , and copy it in the variables

Need output as

```
Date = 6

Month = "Apr"
```

Can anyone please help with this using regular expressions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried using this following regex 

match = re.search(r'(Date: [0-9]{1,2}?\s*(?:[–-]\s*[0-9]{1,2}?)?\s+(?:Jan\.|Feb\.|Mar|Apr|May|June|July|Aug\.|Sept\.|Oct.|Nov\.|Dec\.)\s*[0-9]{4})+?(+0000)', date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex with multiline mode `m`:

```
^Date:[^,]+,\ (\d+) (\w+)
```

This will capture the date and the month in groups 1 and 2 respectively, so the match can easily be unpacked into two variables like so:

```
date, month = re.search("^Date:[^,]+,\ (\d+) (\w+)", Data, re.MULTILINE).groups()
date = int(date)

print(date, month)
# output: 6 Apr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract the date

**Ex:**

```
import re
from dateutil.parser import parse

s = """-------- Forwarded Message --------

Subject:    Sample Report

Date:   Thu, 6 Apr 2017 16:39:19 +0000

From:   test1@abc.com

To:     test2@xyz.com"""

date = re.search("Date(.*)$", s, re.MULTILINE)
if date:
    date = date.group().replace("Date:", "").strip()
    d = parse(date)
    Date = d.day
    Month = d.strftime("%b")
print(Date, Month)
```

**Output:**

```
6 Apr
```

Comment: That gives an output of `Date:   Thu, 6 Apr 2017 16:39:19 +0000`. How is that useful in the slightest?

Comment: i only want the date (6) and month("Apr") to be extracted and saved in a variable. not the entire sentence bro.

Comment: @Rakesh : yes i got the answer as expected . Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the solution of @Rakesh,

```
import re
from datetime import datetime

data1 = re.sub(' ', '', data)
res = re.search(r'Date(.*)$', data1, re.MULTILINE).group()
res2 = datetime.strptime(res, 'Date:%a,%d%b%Y%X%z')
print(res2.day, res2.month)
```